# Positioning wheel images on top of different car models images using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I'm working on a web app which is a basic car visualizer using vanilla JavaScript. It shows the users a car model and a list of wheels. Users can select a wheel which will be then displayed on top of the car model.

For the very first car model, I used CSS styling to position the new wheel images on car model. And when the user changes the wheels, all the wheels perfectly fit over the car model.

Here's the HTML and CSS code for the positioning:

```css
.v-vehicle-vis-container {
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: center;
}
.v-vehicle-image {
  width: 700px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.v-wheels {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.v-wheels.front-wheel {
  top: 147px;
  left: 469px;
  width: 48px;
}
.v-wheels.rare-wheel {
  top: 146px;
  left: 181px;
  width: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div class="v-block v-card v-vehicle-vis" id="">
    <div class="v-vehicle-vis-container">
        <img src="./images/Car Models/2000 Integra R/1280veh.0integra.15.Black.png" alt=""
            class="v-vehicle-image">
        <img src="./images/wheel-1-s.png" class="v-wheels front-wheel" alt="" srcset="">
        <img src="./images/wheel-1-s.png" class="v-wheels rare-wheel" alt="" srcset="">
    </div>
</div>
```

It gives this output:
[Output of very first car model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eddyw.png)

When I change the car model, since the wheels have absolute positioning, they will be exactly there but the new car model obviously has different dimensions so the wheels will not be placed properly:
[Output of new car model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvbnn.png)

The solution I have in my mind is to check wheels absolute 'top' and 'left' positions for every car model and placed all the values in a JS object, so that every car model will have a reference of wheels positions and will implement it accordingly.

This solution seems to work if there are a few other car models. But if there are hundreds or thousands of car models, this will take forever to check position of wheels for every car model.

Wondering if there's any solution like automating the process of detecting car wheels position and placing new wheels exactly there for every car model.

Thank you.

Comment: The solution you have in mind is probably the best. Detecting wheels' position in an image would require machine learning probably.

Comment: You are right @KonradLinkowski. And for this, I was thinking of creating a python script based on object detection mechanism.  And through that, I can generate a data set of front and rare wheels positions for each car model.

Comment: I suspect you will have to measure up for every model, but I notice you are using px values. Think of storing wheel positions in % terms (% of the image dimensions) so your solution is responsive.

Comment: @AHaworth as per my understanding of your solution, I don't think this would work. It's because for every car image, how could I detect the top and left position or the center of original wheels in the car image. For example if a car model has its wheels top position of 80%, the next car model will not have the same percentage, it might have 82%. So I think the problem is still there.

Comment: Yes of course you have to measure up for every model, there is no way round this unless you can find a very intelligent system that understands what a car is and what wheel arches are etc. What I am suggesting is that for each model you store the % offsets within  the image itself so for each image things can get placed correctly, and don't use px values in your CSS.

Comment: You're right @AHaworth. Thank you for the proposed solution.

Comment: Can recommend, to position wheels in photoshop, read the psd file with node script and generate some json